# Saving space in a windows server 2008 workstation

Tags: windows-server-2008, disk-space

> **Related Question:**
>   [Why does the /winsxs folder grow so large, and can it be made smaller?](https://superuser.com/questions/1/why-does-the-winsxs-folder-grow-so-large-and-can-it-be-made-smaller)

My server 2008 installation drive is eating space like anything. Specially the winsxs folder.
Trying compress it results in a “*file/folder is currently accessed*” error.

Any suggestions to free up hard disk space?

Comment: This is not a duplicate solely because the difference between this and the first question is the issue of space. Vista and Server 2008 is the same platform so the same advice will apply.

Comment: Disk cleanup will reduce the size of winsxs folder if you delete old windows updates, run disk cleanup and when it completes click the "clean up system files" button, it will grind for a while, then tick the Windows Update Cleanup box, then ok, it will remove GB of old updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For winsxs see this [article](http://www.winvistaclub.com/f16.html). The most relevant part is:

> The Winsxs folder, stores multiple
>   copies of dll's in order to let
>   multiple applications run in Windows
>   without any compatibility problem.

My advice is not to touch this folder. It's essential for Windows.

The only general advice for saving space is to uninstall the Windows software that you don't need. Anything else is dangerous grounds.

**EDIT**
You can, however, delete the contents of the Windows temporary files directory at `C:\Windows\Temp`.