# Converting FAT32 to NTFS without formatting (server 2008)

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, formatting, disk-space, fat32

I have a FAT32 partition in windows server 2008 machine. How can I convert the partition to NTFS without formatting?

My intention is to resize the partition and add some [more space to my primary installation drive](https://superuser.com/questions/36752/saving-space-in-a-windows-server-2008-workstation)

P.S. [Partition magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PartitionMagic) exits with errors on server 2008.

Comment: I'm not at work to try: Does windows 2008 no longer have the "convert" command?

Comment: Server 08 still has the "convert" command. just verified.

Comment: Well, there you go then :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this in the command line

> convert X: /fs:ntfs

change "X:" to the letter of the drive you would like to convert.

Comment: will it format the drive/partition?

Comment: @Learner, it doesn't make reformatting, only converting.

Answer (score 1):

To resize the partition, you will need a server class product.  There is a server class version of Partition Magic, but it's expensive.  If you must enlarge the C: partition, then I would suggest performing a FULL BACKUP first.  Then, use GPartEd (free, linux-based partitioning software).

As stated by scoopdreams, the command CONVERT should work for converting your partition from FAT32 to NTFS (note: Convert CANNOT convert back to FAT32).