# changing a ntfs disk to fat32 without farmating and removing the disk

Tags: windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, ntfs, fat32

I have a external hard drive that is full of data and i need all of it .
I need to change it from ntfs to fat32.

Is there any application that lets me change it without formatting and even removing the disk and change it with all of its data to fat32 disk?

Thank for your help.

Comment: I wonder why you would voluntarily go to an older and inferior format? Check here about the disadvantages and limitations: http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2421454,00.asp ? You might well find out that it doesn't solve any issue you are trying to solve, but instead introduces new issues; some files might be too large to get stored there even. - What you are really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Aganju play station 3 just can read fat32 hard drives

Comment: If you have files larger then 4 GB on the drive, this cannot be done, [even if it is possible](http://superuser.com/questions/115074/convert-ntfs-to-fat32-without-losing-data) so backup all your data before you try conversion attempts.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not possible. What your asking to do is about equivalent to scrapping your house and rebuilding it as a different house while you keep living in it.

You do need to copy all data to another place (outside of that partition), reformat, and then copy back.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Whether it's worth the effort is debatable, but it's possible.

Comment: How would you do that, @Tetsujin?

Comment: see the links in the question comments. Personally., i'd use iPartition, but I'm on Mac, not Win.