# I want to move winsxs folder to another drive. Possible?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, junction, winsxs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can winsxs be moved and if so how?](https://superuser.com/questions/184839/can-winsxs-be-moved-and-if-so-how)

My SSD is running out of space.  The `winsxs` folder is by far the biggest holder of space. So I wanted to move the folder to another drive, then make a junction to actually point to the new location.

The stumbling block is that to create a junction, you must delete the source folder.  And I can't do that because Windows won't let me. It states that `TrustedInstaller` user owns the folder and I can't do anything about it.  I attempted to take ownership of the folder but windows simply won't let me.

My questions are as follows:

1. What I am trying to do...is it safe?
2. How do I take ownership of the `winsxs` folder?