# How can I check the actual size used in an NTFS directory with many hardlinks?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, hardlink

On a Win7 NTFS volume, I'm using cwrsync which supports --link-dest correctly to create "snapshot" type backups. So I have:

```
z:\backups\2010-11-28\cygdrive\c\Users\...
z:\backups\2010-12-02\cygdrive\c\Users\...
```

The content of 2010-12-02 is mostly hardlinks back to files in the 2010-11-28 directory, but there are a few new or changed files only in 2010-12-02. On linux, the 'du' utility will tell me the actual size taken by each incremental snapshot. On Windows, explorer and du under cygwin are both fooled by hardlinks and shows 2010-12-02 taking up a little more space than 2010-11-28.

Is there a Windows utility that will show the correct space acutally used?

Comment: Tools addressing this would be very helpful in getting an accurate picture of [Why does the /winsxs folder grow so large, and can it be made smaller?](http://superuser.com/questions/1/why-does-the-winsxs-folder-grow-so-large-and-can-it-be-made-smaller) and

Comment: this seems to be the de-factor question & answers for normal disk usage: [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using [Sysinternals Disk Usage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651.aspx) (otherwise know as `du`), specifically using the `-u` and `-v` flags will only count unique occurrences, and will show the usage of each folder as it goes along.

As far as I know the file system doesn't show the difference between the original file and a hard link (that is really the point of a hard link) so you can't discount them on a folder-by-folder basis, but need to do this comparatively.

To test I created a random folder with 6 files in to. Cloned the whole thing. Then created several hard and soft links inside the first folder to reference other files in the first folder, and also some in the second.

Running `du -u -v testFld` results in (note the values next to the folders are in KiB):

```
       104  <path>\testFld\A
        54  <path>\testFld\B
       149  <path>\testFld

Totals:
Files:        12
Directories:  2
Size:         162,794 bytes
Size on disk: 162,794 bytes
```

Running `du -u -v testFld\a` results in:

```
104  <path>\testFld\a
...
```

Running `du -u -v testFld\b` results in:

```
74   <path>\testFld\b
...
```

Notice the mismatch?
The symlinks in A that refer to files in B are only counted against A during the "full" run, and B only returns 54 (even though the files were originally in B and hard-linked from A). When you measure B seperately (or, if you don't use the `-u` unique flag) it will count its "full" measure of 74.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the sysinternals du, just the cygwin one. Apparently the cygwin du does what I want as well, I just didn't think to try it before starting the bounty.

Comment: This answer confuses the function of the `-u` flag. You get the *"full" measure* if you **use** the `-u` flag. Without it, it only counts 1 instance of any hard-linked file. Says so in the docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/du and testing verifies it.

Comment: 10 years later, using W10. There is a `du` command in W10. But this doesn't have either `-u` or `-v` as switches. Instead, download from the link and use the appropriate .exe for your system (64 bit or not), changing the name of the file as appropriate and putting it somewhere appropriate in your PATH locations.

Answer (score 5):

PowerShell 5 may be an option. It is available for Windows 7 but I only tested this on a Server 2012 R2 with the [April 2015 Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46889)

The filesystem provider in PowerShell 5 has two new properties `LinkType` and `Target`:

```
ls taskmgr.exe | fl LinkType,Target
```

this returns:

```
LinkType : HardLink
Target   : C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-advancedtaskmanager_..._6.3.9600.17..2\Taskmgr.exe
```

So now I can only show all files in system32 that are not hardlinks:

```
cd $env:SystemRoot\System32
ls -Recurse -File -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? LinkType -ne HardLink | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
```

this returns:

```
Count    : 844
Sum      : 502,486,831
```

you can compare that with all files:

```
ls -Recurse -File -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum

Count    : 14092
Sum      : 2,538,256,262
```

So over 13,000 files with 2GB+ are hardlinks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ln.exe](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html) to show the "true size" of a directory tree:

```
ln.exe --truesize z:\backups\.
```

It will only detect hardlinks below that starting folder.

Comment: This answer is very useful, because people who excessively work with hardlinks probably will have installed the Link Shell Extension and `ln.exe` anyway.

Comment: I downloaded this and found it to be invaluable when experimenting with all this stuff, which is tricky! One of the simplest ways is to monitor the amount of free space remaining ("Available") using (WSL) `df` for your drive.  Using `rsync` with the `--link-dest` option, which specifically says that it makes use of hard links, is one example of how to use this hard link for snapshotting. So you make one snapshot, modify one of the files in the source location, do another snapshot, and see how much your "Available" disk space has changed. Then confirm presence of hard links using `ln.exe`.

Comment: NB also bear in mind that the reduction in disk space will inevitably be somewhat larger than the files which have changed and thus **can't** be snapshotted as a hard link: because hard links themselves (for all other, unchanged files) take up a non-zero amount of disk space!

Answer (score 1):

[TreeSize Professional](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/) (~$55, 30 day trial) claims to distingish NTFS hardlink disk space. A quick trial seems to bear this out.

Hardlink support is not turned on out of the box: go to *Tools > Options > Scan*, re-scan, then use `Ctrl-1` and `Ctrl-2` to switch between *Size* and *Allocated* space. *Allocated* is actual space used, while *Size* is the statistic normally reported by other programs.

There is a performance penalty for turning on hardlink support (and symlinks and mounts too if you want that also). The colour palette is garish for my taste, but that seems to be par for the course in this genre. Also be careful when clicking around in the box chart area -- it's easy to accidentally move a folder with a mistaken drag-n-drop when you only meant to expand it.

Comment: LOL. At `Allocated` the program seems to show 1/2 the real size when there are two links (original file + 1 hard link), 1/3 the real size when there are three links (original file + 2 hard links)... 1/n the real size when there are n links (original file + [n-1] hard links) . A 60MB file plus 1 hard link shows a `Allocated` size (for the hard link) of 30MB. Not a very useful behavior, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

I also do some research about this question. Here is the results I discovered.

The folder size containing hardlinked files in NTFS may be considered in three different meanings:

1. Size including sizes of all hardlinked files (which is shown by WE).
2. Size of unique files only in terms of the current folder.
3. Size of unique files only in terms of the whole disk.

The number 2 is what is shown by TreeSize Professional, in Details tab, Allocated column, if option "Track NTFS hardlinks" is enabled.

Here is exaple for winsxs folder (7.5Gb in opposition for 10):

[image]

Receiving number 3 value is still a question for me. Although I was able to get a lower bound by using Total Commander with NL_Info plugin. What I have got is a size occupied by files which have onle one hardlink (unique files). It was about 5Gb for a given example.

So trying to expand harrymc answer or say in other words.

Answer (score 0):

I think some facts need to be set right here.

Windows cannot "detect" hardlinks, since every file is actually a hardlink to a bunch of bytes on the disk.

The du tool detects duplicates, but that is false too, since if folder A contains files and B only contains hardlinks to the files in A, then du of A *and* du of B will return the same answer - the size of the files coming originally from A, but these files are now also in B.

This is actually correct, since for example if you deleted A then its files will not be deleted
on the disk, because they are still referenced by B. With hard-links, which file is the source and which one is the hard-link is quite arbitrary and meaningless.

Products such as du will list a directory while discounting duplicates.
This will only work if all files and hard-links are contained in one directory.
Many folder-list products do that.

Conclusion: With hard-links, the question of "the actual size used in an NTFS directory" is meaningless.

Comment: Hesitate to take issue with a 349k rep ... but this surely isn't right. You can monitor available disk space, and find that if you are using `rsync` correctly with the `link-dest` option your disk space declines after a snapshot operation less than if you had done a simple second copy of the files. Admittedly you talked about the "actual size... in a **directory**" ... but the "actual size in your partition" is far from "meaningless".  Use of the ln.exe tool in combination with the Linux `df` command, which shows "Available" partition space, IMHO: see my comment to Limer's answer.

Comment: @mikerodent: Answer from 2012 and could have been better written, but these are two different issues.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to find the change in available space left in your partition. If your snapshotting is working correctly this will mean that if you do an `rsync` (or `cwrsync`) using `--link-dest` (the docs for which specifically say it will use hard links for identical files) on a directory where some of the files haven't changed, this will eat up less of the available partition space than if you had done a simple copy.

I have been inspired by a couple of the answers to find the solution which works for me. The chosen answer by DMA57361 didn't seem to work that clearly for me: firstly, by the way, at the time of writing, 2021, there is already a `du` command in W10, but it is not the one used in DMA57361's question: she/he has a link where you can get hold of the right du.exe (or du64.exe).

I'm actually using `rsync` in WSL, so I naturally used the BASH `df` command to find out how my operations were affecting the available space. But if you're doing something in the normal W10 CLI console you can use `dir`, which also shows the total disk space available in the current partition at the end:

```
08/10/2019  16:57    <DIR>          software projects
19/02/2021  08:04    <DIR>          Videos
               6 File(s)      3,695,481 bytes
              35 Dir(s)  38,383,546,368 bytes free
```

It works just as you might hope: say you have 20 files in a directory. You do one snapshot, using `rsync`, and then you modify one of those 20 files, and then do another `rsync`, referencing the first snapshot directory using `--link-dest`, and then check the change in available partition space. What you find is that the space has declined by much less than the volume of all 20 files. It will in fact have declined by more than the size of the one modified file, and the reason for this must be (I assume) that the newly created hard links (19 of them) take up non-zero disk space.

You can confirm that there are then hard links present by running the `ln.exe` command from Limer's answer: this will show that there are 19 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Sysinternals `du` one can utilize `du` from Cygwin.

Modern Cygwin understand lots kinds of links on Windows (WSL/hardlinks/etc).

GNU `du` is much powerful that Sysinternals'.