# Deleted contents of winsxs folder and BSOD

Tags: windows-7, bsod, winsxs

[What can I safely delete from the "C:\WINDOWS" folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/346848/what-can-i-safely-delete-from-the-c-windows-folder/1030275)

I deleted the contents of that folder and my Windows 7 BSODs now.

Do I have to reinstall?

Comment: Why are you throwing a tantrum like a child? Nobody is obliged to answer your question. And you even accepted an answer. So that means the question *is* answered.

Comment: I am not acting like a child, My comments are out of context, they were in reply to Bummy's useless comment, which has been removed. Bummy was the first to reply before the only useful reply by Ouroborus was posted but their reply was useless. I thought this was a site for asking/answering questions, sorry about the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.howtogeek.com/174705/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-your-winsxs-folder-on-windows-7-or-8/

> The WinSXS folder contains all Windows system components. In fact,
>   component files elsewhere in Windows are just links to files contained
>   in the WinSXS folder. The WinSXS folder contains every operating
>   system file.

So, yes, you'll have to reinstall.

(I'm curious how you managed to delete those files. That's a system folder, at least some of them would have been in use, and it would've taken some effort to get them deleted.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. They shouldn't have said it was safe to delete there :(

Comment: They didn't. Answers there clearly state you shouldn't touch WinSxs at all. This is natural selection. Nothing more.

Comment: The question was what can I **safely** delete and the top answer said that folder was the biggest chunk of junk. It was implied. I still feel a little dumb for not making sure.

Comment: Disagree, it was not implied.

Comment: I dare you to say that after you try booting after deleting your winsxs folder