# Why does my Windows folder use 75 GB?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the /winsxs folder grow so large, and can it be made smaller?](https://superuser.com/questions/1/why-does-the-winsxs-folder-grow-so-large-and-can-it-be-made-smaller)
>   [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

My dad has asked me to have a look at his computer so see what is wrong it because he keeps running out of space on his C drive. I had a look and noticed that his C:\Windows folder is 75 GB large.

I've never seen one that big was wondering if there is a common cause for this.

He's running Windows XP Pro Service Pack 3. I had a look inside the directory and the only really big folder is System32 which is sitting at 2.16GB. I can't see where the 75GB figure is coming from.

Comment: try useing explorer xp to work out where the size of the folders and files actualy are.

Comment: Download link for Explorer XP?

Comment: http://www.explorerxp.com/index.html#download

Comment: Ok I downloaded Explorer XP and there was 67GB in C:\WINDOWS\Installer Windows hadn't been deleting updates. I deleted them, hopefully that wont have broken anything...

Comment: How is this a dupe?

Comment: @OmarKooheji To check which files / folders make up the size. Am I missing something?

Comment: As far as I can see, this one isn't related to winsxs, so it 's a different question. I\m voting to reopen.

Comment: @AndrejaKo FWIW, I voted to close as a duplicate of the file system usage visualization. It seems the OP found the files using such a tool anyway. Sathya must have picked the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Treesize free: http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/

It displays a tree of your disk with the size of each dir and its subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded Explorer XP as directed by ben950'scomment there was 67GB in C:\WINDOWS\Installer Windows hadn't been deleting updates.

I deleted them, hopefully that wont have broken anything...

Comment: That doesn't just hold windows installs/updates it can hold many other (I think) MSI type installs. Deleting it wont really break anything, you just won't be able to do program/driver repair installs, and uninstalls. . . . Without having to re-install the package. re-install can fail in many (more than some) cases because the item is still installed.   Basically it IS a good way to clean-up some, as long as you understand the surprises you will see when using Add/Remove. (for that install type)