# Cleanmgr.exe does not show option to clean installed service packs

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, restore, service-pack, disk-cleanup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the /winsxs folder grow so large, and can it be made smaller?](https://superuser.com/questions/1/why-does-the-winsxs-folder-grow-so-large-and-can-it-be-made-smaller)

I copied Cleanmgr.exe and Cleanmgr.exe.mui as it was suggested [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/c85b9dc7-5ae2-497f-b28a-80d0f648417f/), but when I run it it shows 4 items (Downloaded files, temp files, recycle bin, thumbnails), then if I click on "Cleanup system files" button and then pick drive C, it does not show anything additional in that list.

I know that my c:\windows\winsxs folder has 22Gb of service packs.

How do I clean it up ?

I want to make them permanent, I don't need to ever roll them back.

Comment: Already answered here...http://superuser.com/a/392029/40928