# Where are "temporary files" cleaned by Windows 7 Disk Cleanup?

Tags: windows-7, temporary-files, disk-cleanup

My disk cleanup seems unable to delete a lot of messages worth of "temporary files" that it sees, even after I went and deleted contents of various temporary folders I found myself. I would like to try delete such files manually, but for this I need to figure out just where are those "temporary files" that Disk Cleanup is detecting and offering to delete.

Any suggestions? What folders does Disk Cleanup examine to tally up the temporary files?

Comment: Why do you want to delete temporary files manually ? Are you saying that you have so much temporary files that disk cleanup cannot cope and leaves a certain volume behind ?

Comment: In my case, I want to know because it's saying i have 5 GB of temp files and I want to know what they are before they are deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "Temporary Files" folder that Disk Cleanup is referring to is the one pointed to by the environment variable `%TEMP%`. You can go directly to this folder by typing `%TEMP%` in the Run box or in the address bar in Windows Explorer.

Disk Cleanup's list of "places to cleanup" is stored in the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches`. The Temporary Files item is in a key named, unsurprisingly, `Temporary Files`.

Comment: The TEMP and TMP environment variables point to the current user's temp file directory only.

Comment: There are system environment variables for TEMP and TMP also. A program can ask for the system variables instead of the user variables.

Comment: In my Windows 7, the system TEMP is `C:\Windows\Temp` but that also doesn't contain [408 GB](https://www.facebook.com/cees.timmerman/posts/10206062924043204?comment_id=10206069052076401&notif_t=feed_comment) of my 1 TB HDD.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find anything other than `%TEMP%` in the registry key mentioned by Patrick, so I tried to log `cleanmgr.exe` using [Process Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor).

`cleanmgr.exe` does a `File System` Class `SetDispositionInformationFile` Operation with `Delete: True` Detail on files in `%TEMP%`, which in my case according to `echo` is equal to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp`

It had already deleted the 3 GB unaccounted for by `%TEMP%` though, and didn't trim the [500+ MB `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log`](https://superuser.com/questions/803842/why-is-cbs-log-file-size-20-gb); I suspect most of my wasted space was in [`winsxs`](https://superuser.com/questions/1/why-does-the-winsxs-folder-grow-so-large-and-can-it-be-made-smaller).

Answer (score -2):

It's very simple to remove all temporary files on Windows 7 64bit or 32-bit. Just do the below:

1. Open (RUN), type `%temp%`, and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. You will find that all temporary files are in that folder. Just remove what you want.

See http://www.get-answer.net/questions/how-to-remove-the-temp-files-in-windows-7-64x/.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: It is also an exact copy of the text in the link without the required quote format. Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). 
You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: The link is broken.