# Is there a way to know what the Windows Disk Cleanup utility will delete?

Tags: windows, windows-8, temporary-files, disk-cleanup

When I run the Disk Cleanup utility that's built into Windows 8, it tells me that it can free up 53GB by deleting 'Temporary Files'. However, a CCleaner analysis on default settings only finds about 300MB worth of space to free up, so I'm wondering what Disk Cleanup has found that CCleaner does not.

Note that [this question](https://superuser.com/q/513381/74422) appears to be similar to what I'm asking, but the accepted answer says that 'Temporary Files' refers to `%TEMP%`. I've already cleared out most of `C:\Users\Cam\AppData\Local\Temp`, and it now has only 230MB of stuff in it, even with system files showing.

So where is this 53GB located? Is there a way to find out what it is?

Edit: I should note that this is on a 110GB SSD, so it's almost half the drive. And in fact I'm only using 86GB, so if it's really going to clear out 53GB, that would be more than 60% of the stuff on my C drive. I'm starting to think that Disk Cleanup caches its analysis, and hasn't updated since I started cleaning up the drive earlier today. Although when I run it it says that it's 'Calculating' how much space can be saved, and it takes about 5-10 seconds to do so. Hmmm...

Edit2: Here is what my hard drive looks like, according to SpaceMonger (Right click->Open image in new tab, so you can see it properly): [image: C:\]

You can see why I was starting to think that the 53GB figure is actually wrong. Even if 'Temporary Files' includes my hiberfil and *everything* in WinSxS (about 13GB total), that would be 26GB, which is only halfway there. Hard to see where there's 53GB of stuff to delete.

Comment: What's the total amount of disk space in the directories that are in the registry key mentioned in that other SU question?

Comment: The only directory in that key is `%TEMP%`, or `C:\Users\Cam\AppData\Local\Temp`, which is only 230MB.

Comment: @CamJackson: Along with memory dump files that may be quite big, it *might* be cleaning Windows Update/hotfix backups or uninstallers. Not sure though. Isn't there a UI as in Win7 showing you what will be deleted and the size of each item?

Comment: @Karan Memory dump files are listed as a separate item, so I don't think they're part of 'Temporary Files'. But anyway, take a look at the image I've added. It's hard to see 53GB worth of anything that could be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, CCleaner doesn't check things like Windows Update temporary/cache files, and those files are usually very big. To clean up the Windows Update cache is not an easy task since I guess it requires complex dependency checking, knowledge about Windows Update state, etc. which is not something that a 3rd party tool can easily know.

It is normal for Disk Cleanup to be able to clean huge amount of file that CCleaner can't.

Answer (score 0):

Is that screenshot from before deleting 53 GB?

If so, it's probably in [WinSxS](https://superuser.com/questions/1/why-does-the-winsxs-folder-grow-so-large-and-can-it-be-made-smaller).

Else it simply failed to delete all of the files.

[SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/) shows sizes per folder block. I'd use that to make before and after screenshots to see which folders got smaller.

Answer (score -1):

it may be that, it cleans space taken by `hibernate`, `page cache memory` , `temporary internet files`, `application data`
and then defraging your drive..
that may be reason, though 53 gb still is huge amount for cleaning data,

Comment: Why would it defrag the drive? That does not usually increase available space, takes a long time and will hurt performance of a non-rotating drive (such as the posters SSD).

Comment: I'm not sure but , after reading 53GB, i thought that may be it will defrag.