# Why doesn't Disk Cleanup clean `%temp%` or `c:\windows\temp`?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, temporary-files, disk-cleanup

*"Back in the day"* it was good to be in the habit of periodically deleting the temp files created in `c:\tmp` by Windows and other software, or else you'd risk filling up your fancy 40MB hard drive (probably the most common cause of [BSOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_screen_of_death)'s back then).

Nowadays, "there's an app for that": **[Windows Disk Cleanup](https://support.microsoft.com/windows/disk-cleanup-in-windows-10-8a96ff42-5751-39ad-23d6-434b4d5b9a68)** . . .

[image]

...but every time it runs, I follow by manually emptying at least 2 other folders:

- `%temp%` (aka `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp`),
- `C:\Windows\Temp`

[image]

There's often 1000's of junk files in those folders, apparently ignored by the disk cleanup tool, so I blindly give 'em the ol' <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> → <kbd>Delete</kbd>, deleting anything that's not locked  — and it's never seemed to cause a problem. (When I'm feeling *really* adventurous, I'll run `cmd` and do a `dir c:\tmp* /s` and see what else is taking up space.)

My question is, **is there a reason these folders aren't included in the 'official' Disk Cleanup tool?**  Is any of that crap likely to be important?

Sure, my current drive has 50,000x the capacity that my 1st HD did, but all that junk must impact performance at least a bit, right?  **And if not**, then why bother with Disk Cleanup at all?

Comment: Disk Cleanup will only remove old files. So what you see remaining is most likely newer files.

Comment: “is there a reason these folders aren't included in the 'official' Disk Cleanup tool?” - They are included but Disk Cleanup will only delete eligible files in those directories. By default it’s 7 days old.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disk Cleanup and Temporary Files](https://superuser.com/questions/1181711/disk-cleanup-and-temporary-files)