# Can't delete/remove temporary files Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, storage, temporary-files, disk-cleanup

I have tried to remove "Temporary files" in Settings > Storage

[image]

[image]

and in Disk Cleanup tool

[image]

But after selecting and running the removing/deleting/cleaning process nothing happens, the "Temporary files" still there 69GB

Why can't I remove it?
I've tried to delete it for the last 3 months, no success...

Comment: [This is because the files must meet a minimum age before they are deleted.](https://superuser.com/questions/1181711/disk-cleanup-and-temporary-files/1181714#1181714)

Comment: I tried it every month for the last 3 months and still no success.

Comment: Navigate to %Temp% and delete your desired files you want removed. Without deep analysis of what files are in that folder I have no additional insight

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding You could try running this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852786/automate-process-of-disk-cleanup-cleanmgr-exe-without-user-intervention/64106041#64106041 and see if that does the trick.

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding https://www.bleachbit.org/

Comment: Try to run that wizard from safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

I basically follow this video but I'm only doing the **%temp%** folder

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOFUy9GHAiY

Open **Run**

Type in **%temp%** and hit enter

The Temp folder will open, **CTRL+A** to select all and **CTRL+DEL** to
delete all files, some files and folders will give you issues
(permission etc.) just "**Skip**" and make sure to check the **Apply for
all files** so that it won't ask you again.

Be sure to stay on screen for at least 3-5 mins until no more pop-ups
and you can leave it to run the deleting process

It deleted 95% of the file and free up my C drive.

I'll see if any software or app breaks after this but so far so good.

Comment: Since the wizard failed to remove them, I doubt you'll be able to. You CAN see what files aren't being deleted, then figure-out what application is not behaving as expected.

Comment: ALSO, you CAN just boot from safe mode and then try to delete them.