# Windows 10 , SSD Drive is not full but shows red bar

Tags: windows-10, ssd, storage, notifications

I've split my SSD to 2 drives, one of them has 44GB and Windows 10 shows the red bar in Computer section and notify me to check the storage.

[image]

but when I'm getting the properties of all files and folders , I used only 27% of 44GB.

[image]

Is there a problem with my SSD or the bug of Windows ?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the dialog is right: the disk is full. It seems to me that the selection you have used to calculate the disk size isn't entirely accurate. Maybe there are hidden or system files that aren't included in your search (for example the recycle bin can take up quite some space and is often excluded from selection).

I would advice to download [SequoiaView](http://www.win.tue.nl/sequoiaview/), an app from the stone age I have used *a lot*. It shows the actual disk usage in a map, so it is really easy to see where you lose the space.

Answer (score 1):

**Duplicate question here on [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/576254/357399) :**

here is the snapshot of [TreeSize](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free) for my F-drive

[image]

**Solution :** 
I got backup from F-drive , Format that and restore the backup . everything works fine!

Comment: System volume information = system restore points, that take most space