# Moving Windows\winsxs\Backup to another drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, junction, winsxs

I've installed an SSD and for a number of big directories (e.g. Users\me\Downloads), I've been able to use the Sysinternals "junction" command to create a hard link on C: that references a copy of the directory on the hard drive that used to be C: and is now D:.

It seems that the winsxs\backup directory is an ideal candidate for this -- anything that thinks it's writing to or reading from c:\windows\winsxs\backup will really be working with d:\whatever\path\I\choose\backup, and it will of course be slower but files there are rarely touched (I'd think).

However, it doesn't seem possible to remove the directory in order to use  to re-create it as a hard link to a directory on D:. Does anyone know a way around that?

Answer (score 1):

don't do this. This folder is used by sfc to restore corrupted files. Moving the folder may break the tool. But you can compress he folder with the NTFS compression after you gave you account full permissions. [Windows 8 does this NTFS compression when I call the WinSxS cleanup](https://superuser.com/a/594216/174557).

[image]

Comment: But a junction made with `mklink` is transparent to the OS, so if the folder is moved e.g. by using @RetroDroid method and then a junction is created, there is no reason that it'll break the sfc tool. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Boot a linux *live cd*, and then do the job... `C:\Windows`other dirs are protected by a *anti-copy* while running win (Microsoft don't want somebody copying windows for its friends...)