# Is it usual to have 14Gb of .dll files? How to reduce it?

Tags: windows-8.1, disk-space

I am trying to free space of my Windows 8.1 drive. I have noticed using WinDirStat that there are almost 14Gb of .dll files. Is this usual? If not, how could I clean the unused .dll files?

[image]

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/1/why-does-the-winsxs-folder-grow-so-large-and-can-it-be-made-smaller

Comment: If they weren't required by the operating system or applications why would they be there? Files don't just show up randomly. So no, none of them are unusual or unnecessary. My suggestion is that you should find some other windmills to tilt at.