# Windows 7 Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) tool fails when trying to clean C:\windows\winsxs

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, disk-cleanup, dism, winsxs

I am running *Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit edition* and I am tyring to run the **Windows 7 Deployment Image Servicing and Management** ***(DISM)*** tool, `DISM.exe`, have to try and clean/reclaim some space from the `C:\windows\winsxs`folder.

These are my results per following the instructions of **@GvS**'s answer from this SO post:  [Why does the /winsxs folder grow so large, and can it be made smaller?](https://superuser.com/questions/1/why-does-the-winsxs-folder-grow-so-large-and-can-it-be-made-smaller)

> C:\>**DISM /online /cleanup-Image /spsuperseded**
>    Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool Version: 6.1.7600.16385
>
> Image Version: 6.1.7601.18489
>
> Service Pack Cleanup can't proceed: No service pack backup files were
>    found. The operation completed successfully.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already cleaned the RTM files or installed Windows 7 with a DVD which already has the Sp1 included. In both cases you can't shrink WinSxS with this command any longer.

You can [only cleanup WinSxS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/10/08/breaking-news-reduce-the-size-of-the-winsxs-directory-and-free-up-disk-space-with-a-new-update-for-windows-7-sp1-clients.aspx) by running disk cleanup after [installing Update KB2852386](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2852386/en-us)

Comment: how can I check to see/confirm if I installed Win7 with an included copy of SP1? tia.

Comment: How did you install Windows7?

Comment: honestly, I don't know... my ex installed it

Comment: I have no idea how to check how Windows was installed. In this case he used the Sp1 ISO or already ran the command. Install the linked update and cleanup older updates with disk cleanup and you're fine.