# Why is my Windows 8.1 WinSXS folder taking up so much space?

Tags: windows, windows-8, winsxs

I bought a TOSHIBA laptop yesterday with Windows 8.1. I used it for 2 days and Windows folder is using 21 GB more. I tried deleting a bunch of apps from WindowsApps folder and removed Win8 bloatware apps. So, the question is why is the Windows folder growing in size and how do I save space on my hard drive?

Comment: It more sounds like you are just coming here to vent, not get a problem solved. There is nothing wrong with having that many files in your windows folder.

Comment: Until you can give us a reason why this shouldn't be the case then this is not a question. Think about the fact that there is 10+ years of software releases, upgrades and backwards compatibility built into the operating system as well as well as a 32/64 bit binary split which effectively duplicates a lot of system files.

Comment: you can clean it up a bit by removing features you don't need and remove old updates: http://superuser.com/a/594216/174557

Answer (score 1):

The [WinSXS growing in folder size](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251565.aspx) is normal. These files will be kept for a time and removed when Windows 8.1 no longer needs them for system restorations or after you uninstall another program.