# Windows 2008 R2 winsxs folder cleanup

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, disk-cleanup, winsxs

I have a Windows 2008 R2 x64 server.  Desktop experience is enabled.  I've applied the KB2852386 from Microsoft that adds the Windows Update Cleanup to the diskcleanup tool.  When I first ran it, it cleaned out about 2GB of windows updates.  However, the winsxs folder still has about 8GB of files/folders in there.  When I run diskcleanup again, it reports 0kb in that folder.  What could be going on here?  I'd really like to clean up this folder.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: is the question answered?

Answer (score 0):

If Diskcleanup already removed all replaced updates, it can't to any to further cleanup this folder in Windows Server 2008 R2.

You must live with this folder size or upgrade to [Windows Server 2012 R2, here you can use DISM to compact the WinSxS folder more by doing a compression and making the current update permanent](https://superuser.com/a/594216/174557) by running this DISM command:

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup /ResetBase
```