# Windows folder is 40Gb. Is it a normal size? Can I reduce it?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I recently installed Win 7 Ultimate SP1 and then installed all available important updates. My Windows folder is very big now.

1. I made sure I have this update
   http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2852386, runned Disk Cleanup
   and checked all that was possible to delete.
2. I also cleaned System Restore with Disk Cleanup tool.
3. Tried to run vsp1cln.exe and compcln.exe, but they were not found on
   my computer.
4. Then tried DISM /online /Cleanup-Image /SpSuperseded command.

After all my Windows folder is 41,261,065,219 bytes. Winsxs is 13,338,604,038 bytes.

- Is this a normal size for Windows folder?
- Is there any way to make it smaller?

Comment: also [why-does-the-winsxs-folder-grow-so-large-and-can-it-be-made-smaller](http://superuser.com/questions/1/why-does-the-winsxs-folder-grow-so-large-and-can-it-be-made-smaller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is normal, and its worse than it sounds as that folder is not actually 40GB. The WinSXS folder is a bunch of symlinks to the same files which artificially increases the reported size of the folder in question.

My Win7 folder is currently sat at 43GB. My very new, little used Windows 8.1 device is already at 13GB.

When we provision Windows 7 virtual machines we assume that the OS disk will require 60GB and provision accordingly. We assume that about 50GB be consumed, the majority of that in the windows directory.

There have been calls for a final rollup of Win 7 to SP2 to prevent this, and I've seen hints from Microsoft employees that it might happen but I wouldn't hold your breath as Windows 7 is out of mainstream support.