# Option to remove old windows update files from Winsxs not available in disk cleanup; KB2852386 IS installed

Tags: windows-7, ssd, disk-cleanup, winsxs

I have update KB2852386 installed so that I can cleanup old update files. I have a 30gb SSD which has absolutely NO space left on it. I want to cleanup my winsxs folder (21GB), but the option in disk cleanup to remove old update files is not present. In fact, disk cleanup does next to nothing to do anything for me. 
I know that I cannot delete winsxs (duh), and I also know that the displayed file size is not "actual". I still would like to know why I cannot choose to clean old update files from disk cleanup.

Windows 7 Ultimate 64

Comment: You know you have to do disk cleanup twice to get the updates? First disk cleanup will open a new window, then you have to  hit "clean up system files" button before it displays windows update files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the /winsxs folder grow so large, and can it be made smaller?](http://superuser.com/questions/1/why-does-the-winsxs-folder-grow-so-large-and-can-it-be-made-smaller)

Answer (score 0):

If the option is not shown, you already removed all possible updates. In this case you can't do any more cleanup. There is an [3rd party tool](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/174816-windows-7-resetbase-backport/) which claims to a much more deeper cleanup, but you have to pay to get it. So I have no idea how good it is.

Comment: hi i am having issue with cleanup yesterday it found 8gb of update file then i clicked clean after one hour i t seem to be frozen then i restarted it now it shows 10 MB of update file size on disk isnt change can u help me?

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar what in detail is your issue?

Comment: 1 st attempt  cleaup froze while removing 8GB of file on 2nd attempt it shows only 79MB can be removed,but no change of size on disk

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar look into the CBS.log if you see any errors.