# How to export all hyperlinks on a webpage?

Tags: hyperlink, webpage

I need a solution to export all hyperlinks on a webpage (on a webpage, not from entire website) and a way to specify the links I want to export, for example only hyperlinks starting with https://superuser.com/questions/ excluding everything else.
Exporting as text file preferred and the results should be displayed one below another, one URL per line:

```
https://superuser.com/questions/1  
https://superuser.com/questions/2  
https://superuser.com/questions/3
[...]
```

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: I have tried `Invoke-WebRequest` in Powershell 5. I use both Windows and Linux, native terminal/Powershell method is preferred.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If Invoke-WebRequest is not returning the HTML for the page your are interested in, you will need to troubleshoot that first. Once your Invoke-WebRequest succeeds, you should be able to parse the resulting HTML to extract what you want. Do not expect us to write the script for you, as DavidPostill indicates; you will need to 'show your work'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running on a Linux or a Unix system (like FreeBSD or macOS), you can open a terminal session and run this command:

```
wget -O - http://example.com/webpage.htm | \
sed 's/href=/\nhref=/g' | \
grep href=\"http://specify.com | \
sed 's/.*href="//g;s/".*//g' > out.txt
```

In usual cases there may be multiple `<a href>` tags in one line, so you have to cut them first (the first `sed` adds newlines before every keyword `href` to make sure there's no more than one of it in a single line).
To extract links from multiple similar pages, for example all questions on the first 10 pages on this site, use a `for` loop.

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do
wget -O - http://superuser.com/questions?page=$i | \
sed 's/href=/\nhref=/g' | \
grep -E 'href="http://superuser.com/questions/[0-9]+' | \
sed 's/.*href="//g;s/".*//g' >> out.txt
done
```

Remember to replace `http://example.com/webpage.htm` with your actual page URL and `http://specify.com` with the preceding string you want to specify.
You can specify not only a preceding string for the URL to export, but also a Regular Expression pattern if you use `egrep` or `grep -E` in the command given above.
If you're running a Windows, consider taking advantage of [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com). Don't forget to select packages `Wget`, `grep`, and `sed`.

Comment: This is almost the method that I use to batch download  music from [KHInsider](http://downloads.khinsider.com) without buying their VIP service. Just manually extract the links and place them in a download manager like [IDM](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using Firefox for it, you can you the addon [Snap Links Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/SnapLinksPlus/)

1. Hold down the right mouse button and drag a selection around the links.
2. When they are highlighted, press and hold Control while letting go of the right mouse button.

Comment: Wouldn't work well due to the selection method, source page can be hundreds of pages long.

Comment: So really no method based on a page won't work, since "source page"  (https://superuser.com/questions/) is only one page and you want it to save from all "hundreds of pages" (like https://superuser.com/questions?page=2)

Comment: That page was only an example.

Comment: But still, what do you mean "hundreds of pages"? If you need to press something to load more pages then it isn't really one page.

Comment: "Approximately", for example this page is that long (though it doesn't have hyperlinks, used as an example due to low size): https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt There are more sites I may want to export links from.

Comment: Oh, got you. This extension for CXhrome seems to do the job https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-klipper-extract-all/fahollcgofmpnehocdgofnhkkchiekoo?hl=en